# multi viewcontrollers and rotation

Tags: iphone

I hope to rotate only one viewcontroller in a multi viewcontroller ( rootviewcontroller and viewcontroller 1, viewcontroller2,..)project.

Is it possible?

I noticed I have to make rootviewcontroller enable shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

But the function willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation in the viewcontroller that I prefer to rotate was not fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sub controllers like :

RootViewController
  FirstViewController
  SecondViewController
  ...

When willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation of RootViewController is called, you need to called yourself the same function of FirstViewController, SecondViewController etc.

For example

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

  [ FirstViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration ];
  [ SecondViewController willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration ];

}
```

By the way, yes you need to implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to say if YES or NO the controller should rotate.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible only make FirstViewController rotate, rootViewcontroller and others do not rotate?

Comment: Hummm if FirstViewController is inside of rootViewcontroller, then rootViewcontroller will rotate if FirstViewController do the same. Try using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in each controller to say if YES/NO they can rotate. If you may have some cases that will bother you ^^ sometimes you must make choice ^^ By the way, take a look at http://www.geckogeek.fr/iphone-forcer-le-mode-landscape-ou-portrait-en-cours-dexecution.html (french but code in english). It could help you to rotate just some controllers in some cases.